# Erro ao atualizar versão do IndexedDB

Tags: javascript, banco-de-dados, indexeddb

Estou com problemas em atualizar a versão do IndexedDB, ele apresenta os seguintes erros.

> Uncaught ConstraintError: Failed to execute 'createObjectStore' on 'IDBDatabase': An object store with the specified name already exists. index.js:11
>   Errorundefined index.js:162
>   Uncaught InvalidStateError: Failed to execute 'transaction' on 'IDBDatabase': The database connection is closing.

Meu código:

```
var request = indexedDB.open("DB_TESTE", 3);
var db = null;

request.onupgradeneeded = function(){
    db = request.result;
    //////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    //                  TABELA PESSOA                          //
    ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

    var pessoa = db.createObjectStore("tbl_PESSOAS", {keyPath: "COD_IDENT_PESSO"});

    pessoa.createIndex("COD_IDENT_PESSO", "COD_IDENT_PESSO", {unique: true});
    pessoa.createIndex("TXT_NOMEX_PESSO", "TXT_NOMEX_PESSO", {unique: false});
    pessoa.createIndex("TXT_APELI_PESSO", "TXT_APELI_PESSO", {unique: false});
    pessoa.createIndex("TXT_FONEX_PESSO", "TXT_FONEX_PESSO", {unique: false});
    pessoa.createIndex("DAT_NASCI_PESSO", "DAT_NASCI_PESSO", {unique: false});
    pessoa.createIndex("TXT_NASCI_PESSO", "TXT_NASCI_PESSO", {unique: false});
    pessoa.createIndex("TXT_NATUR_PESSO", "TXT_NATUR_PESSO", {unique: false});
    pessoa.createIndex("FLG_SEXOX_PESSO", "FLG_SEXOX_PESSO", {unique: false});
    pessoa.createIndex("FLG_ESTAD_CIVIL", "FLG_ESTAD_CIVIL", {unique: false});
    pessoa.createIndex("FLG_IDENT_PESSO", "FLG_IDENT_PESSO", {unique: false});
    pessoa.createIndex("TXT_EMAIL_PESSO", "TXT_EMAIL_PESSO", {unique: false});
    pessoa.createIndex("TXT_SENHA_USUAR", "TXT_SENHA_USUAR", {unique: false});
    pessoa.createIndex("BLO_FOTOX_PESSO", "BLO_FOTOX_PESSO", {unique: false});
    pessoa.createIndex("TXT_ENDER_CEPXX", "TXT_ENDER_CEPXX", {unique: false});
    pessoa.createIndex("TXT_ENDER_BAIRR", "TXT_ENDER_BAIRR", {unique: false});
    pessoa.createIndex("TXT_ENDER_LOGRA", "TXT_ENDER_LOGRA", {unique: false});
    pessoa.createIndex("TXT_ENDER_NUMER", "TXT_ENDER_NUMER", {unique: false});
    pessoa.createIndex("TXT_ENDER_COMPL", "TXT_ENDER_COMPL", {unique: false});
    pessoa.createIndex("COD_IDULT_ATUAL", "COD_IDULT_ATUAL", {unique: false});
    pessoa.createIndex("DAT_ULTIM_ATUAL", "DAT_ULTIM_ATUAL", {unique: false});

}

request.onsuccess = function(){
    //database connection established 
    db = request.result;
    console.log("Conectado corretamente");
}

request.onerror = function(event){
    console.log("Error" + event.target.errorCode);
}
```

Comment: Os objects stores são persistentes, não serão apagados sem que você mande, logo, você não pode tentar criá-los novamente com o `createObjectStore`

Comment: Como faço para apaga-los ?

Comment: Usando o método `deleteObjectStore` (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/IDBDatabase/deleteObjectStore)

Comment: Deu este error Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function

Comment: Como está chamando?

Comment: E onde está declarando "indexedDB"?

Comment: Logo acima, var request = indexedDB.open("DB_MINHACELULA", 4);
var db = null;

Comment: Tente usar algo como `db.deleteObjectStore(...)`

Comment: Tem alguma forma de deletar todo banco de dados, não apenas tabela e criar tudo novamente, com a versão 1 ?

Comment: Tipo da um reset na memoria, para começar, porque na hora que salvo ele começa salvar do numero onde parou, ou seja não deletou a tabela e não criou outra.

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/27647/discussion-between-rafael-telles-and-renan-rodrigues).